# Push to an existing code to an existing repository: Bitcucket

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I have a private repository (Suppose: rental)

I pushed some to code to it. Now I want to push another project to that repository. Clearly, I want to replace the previous code with new one.

With command line what will be the procedure?

```
git remote show origin


* remote origin
  Fetch URL: https://nafeeur10@bitbucket.org/xxxxx/rental.git
  Remote branch:
    master new (next fetch will store in remotes/origin)
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (local out of date)
```

This is now the condition.

I am trying with these commands:

```
1. git init
2. git commit -m "New Commit"
```

Giving me this error:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'github/master'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Comment: You can't easily do this without a force command, assuming the histories are unrelated.  What would be wrong with putting this new code into a new repository?

Comment: I have mentioned the error in last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: `git push --set-upstream origin master` to push to your remote repository called `origin`.

Comment: Telling: Branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'origin'.

Comment: ```git branch --set-upstream-to master  https://nafeeur10@bitbucket.org/xxxx/rental.git```

After giving this.
Telling me:

```fatal: branch 'https://nafeeur10@bitbucket.org/cypriotxx/rental.git' does not exist```